# Count number of cells that don't contain a value in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

I was trying to count the number of cells in a column that don't have the value 0 with this but it wasn't working

```
=COUNTIF(D2:D217, "<0", D2:D217, ">0")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the syntax for does not equal

```
<>
```

Which would give you

```
=COUNTIF(D2:D217, "<>0")
```